# Error response from daemon: mount denied:

Tags: windows, docker

Soy nuevo usando docker, este es un contenedor que se montaba en Linux, como hago para poder usarlo en windows? me tira este error

> $ docker-compose up time="2023-04-20T17:35:33-03:00" level=warning
> msg="The "SSH_KEY" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank
> string." time="2023-04-20T17:35:33-03:00" level=warning msg="Found
> orphan containers ([docker-backend-dimension-1 docker-frontend-1
> docker-backend-adjustment-1]) for this project. If you removed or
> renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command
> with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up." Container
> docker-redis-1  Created Container docker-app-1  Recreate Error
> response from daemon: mount denied: the source path
> "\Users\jcche/.ssh/id_rsa:C:\Users\jcche/.ssh/id_rsa:rw" too many
> colons